# Running and deploying JSP examples

Tags: eclipse, jsp, deployment, jsp-tags, java-ee-5

I have downloaded javaeetutorial5.zip. There are many examples in that zip file.

How i can import those examples to eclipse, How i can deploy and run straight away.

I am using Eclipse IDE (Luna).
Glassfish 4.0 Server

Answer (score 0):

A strong recommendation: If you are learning from tutorials, use the [newest version](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/).

And you might want to try the Oracle examples firstly as it and use Netbeans IDE and only later when trying out your own project move to your favorite IDE. With eclipse you can either use the project wizard to create a Java EE application or better, use maven and let it create a project via archetype, e.g. the one from [Adam bien](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/setting_up_java_ee_7).